# angular rxjs mergeMap/flatMap instead of multiple pipe/subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Below is an example of code.
Show me please an example, how this code can be improved using features like mergeMap/combine observables.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.getRound(params.id)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((round: any) => {
        this.round = round;
        this.getStats(params.id, round.required_tickets)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
          .subscribe((stats: any) => {
            this.stats = stats;
          });
      });
  });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            switchMap((params: any) => {
                this.params = params
                return this.getRound(params.id)
            }),
            switchMap((round: any) => {
                this.round = round;
                return this.getStats(this.params.id, round.required_tickets)
            })
        )
        .subscribe((stats: any) => {
            this.stats = stats;
        });
}
```

Plus, I would definitely not use any as types

Comment: You probably are fine with just ONE `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` and this should be the last operator in the pipeline, read this https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: This stackblitz demonstrates what Picci is talking about. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-woppok S2 will continue to work after Stop 1 has been clicked. S4 will not work after Stop 2 has been clicked.

Comment: @KurtHamilton tnx, I've checked that example. Now I understand that the order makes sense.

Comment: @Picci + I have to declare extra class property - `params`

Comment: Is there a way to pass the round.id from one switchMap to the next one without the class property?

Comment: Yes, like this `switchMap((round: any) => {
                this.round = round;
                return this.getStats(this.params.id, round.required_tickets)
            }).pipe(map(stats => ({stats, roundId})`. You can read [this](https://medium.com/@enrico.piccinin/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a). It talks about http calls, but the concepts apply to rxjs in general.

Comment: @Picci alright. I've done it this way. Works good. https://pastebin.com/pLkgdrNY

Comment: @Picci ofcourse, I will replace the `any` types later. I will define interfaces for that.